# Filter array of objects by property with array of strings with an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I have data that looks like this:

```
    const data = [
      { foo: ["0001|main|0002", "0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0016"] },
      { foo: ["0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0018", "0001|main|0019"] },
      { foo: []},
      { foo: ["0001|main|0001", "0001|main|0012", "0001|main|0022"] },
    ];
```

And I need to filter it with an array of strings that looks like this:

```
let selections = ["0014", "0016"];
```

I need to match the items with the same last for numbers only in the data,
I currently have this which sort of works:

```
data.filter((item) => {
 if(!item.foo.length) return false;
 return selections.every((id) => item.foo.split('|')[2] === id)
});
```

The issue I'm having that when selecting two IDs like above it returns nothing.
I was expecting the return value to be this:

```
[
 {foo: ["0001|main|0002", "0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0016"]},
 {foo: ["0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0018", "0001|main|0019"]},
]
```

I works fine when selection has only one string in it. I think its searching for items that match both strings in the selection.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want `some`, not `every`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want

```
["0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0018", "0001|main|0019"]
```

to be included, it sounds like you need *at least one* of the selections to match, rather than *every* selection to have a match. So, use `.some` instead of `.every`.

```js
const data = [
  { foo: ["0001|main|0002", "0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0016"] },
  { foo: ["0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0018", "0001|main|0019"] },
  { foo: []},
  { foo: ["0001|main|0001", "0001|main|0012", "0001|main|0022"] },
];
const selections = ["0014", "0016"];

const result = data.filter(
  ({ foo }) => selections.some(
    sel => foo.some(
      str => str.endsWith(sel)
    )
  )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Never mind, just realised there are more issues...

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, that worked! I'm not too familiar with every and some methods. I'll have to take a close looks at them and their differences.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current solution is you are trying to use the split() method on an array and the split method is intended for strings.

I am sure there may be cleaner ways to approach this issue but here is what I came up with quickly.

You will have to first iterate through your data array, then iterate over each of item.foo's children elements. This then allows you to run a similar check to what you were doing just as a ternary operation instead that will push all the desired items to a dummy array which can then be returned as the result.

```js
const data = [{
    foo: ["0001|main|0002", "0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0016"]
  },
  {
    foo: ["0001|main|0014", "0001|main|0018", "0001|main|0019"]
  },
  {
    foo: []
  },
  {
    foo: ["0001|main|0001", "0001|main|0012", "0001|main|0022"]
  },
];

let selections = ["0014", "0016"];


const filteredItems = [];

data.forEach((item) => {
  item.foo.forEach(fooItem => {
    if (!fooItem.length) return false;
    selections.every((id) => fooItem.split('|')[2] === id ? filteredItems.push(item.foo) : false);
  })
});


console.log(filteredItems)
```